# 論理否定演算子の前後の空白は可読性をよくするため？

Tags: javascript

同じプログラムの中に以下のコードがあり、下の方は`!`の前後に空白が入っています。
調べてみてもこの2つの違いが分からず、たぶん可読性を良くするためじゃないかと思っているのですが、何か意味が変わったりするのでしょうか？

**例1:**

```
if (!hoge) {
  return false;
}
```

**例2:**

```
if ( ! hoge) { 
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> たぶん可読性を良くするためじゃないかと思っている

そうです。組織のコーディングルールもあるかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。コーディングルールの違いということが分かりスッキリしました

Answer (score 4):

`!`の後ろにも空白が入るのはWordPressのJavaScriptコーディング規約のようですね。
以下抜粋に書いてあるように読みやすさとPHPファイルとの一貫性のためでしょう。

一方JavaScriptのライブラリやユーザー的な例だと`!`の後ろに空白は入らないようです。
あとjQueryは`!`の前に空白を入れるようですが、AirbnbとかNode.jsでは入れないようです。

以下はそれぞれの記事から該当部分を抜粋しています。
[Home/Team Handbook/WordPress コーディング規約ハンドブック/WordPress コーディング規約/JavaScript コーディング規約](https://ja.wordpress.org/team/handbook/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/javascript/)

> スペース
> スペースはコードの中で自由に使えます。「悩んだら、スペースを入れてください」
>
> 十分にスペースが入ることで、開発者はコードが読みやすくなります。仮にファイルサイズが増加しても、後続の縮小プロセスにより不要なスペースは削除され、ブラウザでのロード、処理に最適化したファイルが作成されます。

> - すべての否定演算子「!」にはスペースを続けください。(*)

> (*): スペースの扱いに関しては WordPress の JavaScript 規約は「jQuery JavaScript Style Guide」よりも若干広めです。この違いは WordPress コードにおける PHP ファイルと JavaScript ファイルとの一貫性の維持から生じています。

> 良いスペースの例

> ```
> // jQuery とは異なり、WordPress では否定演算子 ! の後にスペースを入れます。// これは PHP 規約との一貫性のためです。while ( ! condition ) {
>     iterating++;
> }
> ```

[JavaScriptのスタイルガイドまとめ(おすすめ4選)](https://qiita.com/takeharu/items/dee0972e5f39bfd4d7c8) から以下3つを紹介。

上記WordPressの`jQuery とは異なり`というのはこの記事の以下の記述でしょう。
[JavaScript Style Guide](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)

> Spacing

> Bad Examples

> ```
> while(!condition) iterating++;
> ```

> Good Examples

> ```
> while ( !condition ) {
>     iterating++;
> }
> ```

以下2つは否定演算子そのものに関するものでは無いですが、記述時の例として。
[Airbnb JavaScript スタイルガイド() {](https://mitsuruog.github.io/javascript-style-guide/)

> - 24.3 プロパティ/メソッドがbooleanの場合は、isVal()またはhasVal()を使用すること。

> ```
> // bad
> if (!dragon.age()) {
>   return false;
> }
>
> // good
> if (!dragon.hasAge()) {
>   return false;
> }
> ```

[Felix's Node.js Style Guide](https://popkirby.github.io/contents/nodeguide/style.html)

> prototype の拡張

> せいかい:

> ```
> var a = [];
> if (!a.length) {
>   console.log('winning');
> }
> ```

Comment: ご丁寧に説明いただきとても理解が深まりました。スタイルガイドも後でじっくり読んでみたいと思います。